Confusion about Proving the Uniqueness of Linear Representation in N-ary Boolean function

$f\in B_n$ is called linear if $f(x_1,\cdots, x_n)=a_0+a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n$ for suitable coefficients $a_0,\cdots, a_n\in \{0,1\}.$ Here $+$ denotes exclusive disjunction (addition modulo 2) and the not written multiplication is conjunction (i.e. $a_ix_i=x_i$ for $a_i=1$ and $a_ix_i=0$ for $a_i=0$)


Show that the above representation of a linear function $f$ is unique.

Notation meaning:
Here $B_n$ stands for the set of all n-ary boolean functions represented by $f:A=\{0,1\}^n\to \{0,1\}=B$,  $B_n=B^A$
Conjunction $\wedge$ which is the multiplication in the function is represented by the truth matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1 &0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Exclusive Disjunction $+$ is represented by the truth matrix$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Here is the hint from the book:

$x_k$ is fictional in $f$ iff $a_k=0$

This is the problem 1 from section 1.1, I really don't know how to do it and it's my first time ever exposure to this subject. I would like a clearer picture of how to approach this problem than the hint, thank you for your help.

Suppose we have two sets of coefficients, $a_i$ and $b_i$, which both produce $f$. Then we can subtract them from each other to make a function that is identically $0$:
$$(b_0-a_0)+(b_1-a_1)x_1+\dots+(b_n-a_n)x_n=0$$
for all choices of $x_i$. But the only way changing $x_i$ doesn't change the value of this expression is if the coefficient on $x_i$ is $0$. So as no $x_i$ change the expression, each $b_i-a_i$ must be $0$. So the collection of coefficients $b_i$ was the same as $a_i$.

I know this is a bit late, but thank you :)
